# sorting using regex

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to sort a list of URL addresses by the following pattern: `HTTP://blah/address/bar-abab-**baaa**.jpg`, `HTTP://blah/address/p-bhdb-**bbii**.jpg`... (the list is sorted alphabetically by the second "word" in each URL). Therefore, I've decided to use RegEx. This is the problematic part of this code:

```
urls = sorted(urls, key=lambda url:re.findall("(?<=-b).*?(?=\.)",url))
```

(every "second word" in each address starts with "-b" and ends up with a full-stop, so the sorting is supposed to be by "bii", "hdb"...)

The regular expression itself finds the above-mentioned pattern, but the sorting doesn't work (this is the result: , 
 ..

Comment: Could you add a runnable example?

Comment: >>> lst=sorted(lst, key=lambda url:re.search("(?<=-b).*?(?=\.)",url).group())
>>> print lst
['/blah/p-bcgj-baih.jpg', '/blah/p-biai-bacj.jpg', '/blah/p-bija-baei.jpg',/blah/p-bacg-bbdb.jpg', ]

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution: any string between the first two hyphens starts with a p, so all I had to do is to find the next hyphen.